# Sorting A Graph Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel macro which updates a graph to represent data on another tab. I also want to sort the graph. I can't seem to manually do this and just record the macro.

I have tried the below code, but get a run time error 424 saying Object Required

```
Sub Productivity_Report_Graph()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    "='Customer Service Report'!$D$2:$D$100"

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = _
    "='Customer Service Report'!$P$2:$P$100"

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = _
    "='Customer Service Report'!$Q$2:$Q$100"

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
    "='Customer Service Report'!$B$2:$B$100"

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues.AutoSort _

End Sub
```

Comment: on what line do you get the error? have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: Apologies, it's the last line that causes the error

Comment: The last line is incomplete `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues.AutoSort _` or as an additional underscore. Remove the underscore `_` in the end. This is used to concatenate the current code line with the next line (just like both would have been written in one line only).

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting the same error message though?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copying my data to another tab, reordering the date here (this updated on the graph instantly) and then hiding the graph.
I did this as part of a larger RPA process but this could be done in an excel macro also.